# Humour: Noble Gases, Music, Feynman diagrams

Tags: soft-question, specific-reference

Google found these lyrics:

```
I love the morn, to see the first Radon,
When the stars Argon,
As the night Krypton,
And, if it’s cloudy, you won’t Xenon.
```

Years ago, I saw approximately the same lyrics with sheet music.  The staffs of the music turned into Feynman diagrams.  I can't remember what other visual gags were involved, and based on what I didn't know then, and still don't know now, about music and physics, I'm sure there were gags that I didn't catch.

Does anyone have a copy?  It dates back to before we all had internet access and drawing software, so if it survives at all it might be as one of those photocopies of a photocopy of a photocopy that used to circulate.

Edit: I was tempted to add a character named Liam.  He (Liam) would scrape his knee on a rock as he stumbled around in the dark.

Edit, more than seven years later.  The question was deemed off-topic and closed, so I can't create an answer, but I found it, at https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:821707/FULLTEXT01.pdf:

[image]

The memory plays tricks ... I had been sure there was a Feynman diagram in there somewhere.

Comment: This question is not about physics.

Comment: This question is not about physics, yet it's entirely appropriate.

Comment: I can't downvote this :)

Comment: @user10851 But it is.

Comment: @Nathaniel Thanks for believing in me.

Comment: @user36538 ... and thank you, too.

Comment: From "More Random Walks in Science" (R L Weber): _This Lied is unusual in that it combines so many puns, wordplays, and physics items in one opus. Circulated at Princeton in 1942, possibly a work  of the  Princeton  chapter  of  the American Institute for Useless Research.  The illustration has been redrawn by Mrs. Brenda Elliott of The Institute  of Physics from a copy supplied  by Francis  E Throw._